# Mongodb cursor is empty in ejs template(Async call inside ejs )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

The following router calls the ejs template to populate the values of cursor in to the html page.

```
router.get('/users_loaded_disconnect', function(req, res) {
    res.render('users_loaded_disconnect',
           {cursor: req.db.collection('notify_user_state_collection').find({})});
});
```

**user_loaded_disconnect.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b> Users Loaded Disconnect </b>
    <ul>
      <% cursor.nextObject(function(err, item) { %>
      <%= JSON.stringify(item) %>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The cursor does not work. However if the cursor is iterated within the router like the following code it prints the value

```
req.db.collection('notify_user_state_collection').find({}).nextObject(function(err, item) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
    });
```

What is wrong in iterating the cursor inside the ejs template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor operation is asynchronous. Ejs will not wait for it to complete, and will continue to render the template before data is available. You can't effectively use callbacks inside ejs templates.